# Remove extra legends in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I have a simple data frame that I'm trying to do a combined line and point plot using `ggplot2`. Supposing my data looks like this:

```
df <- data.frame(x=rep(1:10,2), y=c(1:10,11:20), 
                 group=c(rep("a",10),rep("b",10)))
```

And I'm trying to make a plot:

```
g <- ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y, group=group))
g <- g + geom_line(aes(colour=group))
g <- g + geom_point(aes(colour=group, alpha = .8))
g
```

The result looks fine with one exception. It has an extra legend showing the `alpha` for my `geom_point` layer.

[image: Extra Legend for <code>geom_point</code> transparency]

How can I keep the legend showing group colors, but not the one that shows my alpha settings?

Answer (score 234, accepted):

Aesthetics can be  *set* or *mapped* within a `ggplot` call.

- An aesthetic defined within `aes(...)` is *mapped* from the data, and a legend created.
- An aesthetic may also be *set* to a single value, by defining it outside  `aes()`.

In this case, it appears you wish to *set* `alpha = 0.8` and *map* `colour = group`.

To do this,

Place the `alpha = 0.8` outside the `aes()` definition.

```
g <- ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y, group = group))
g <- g + geom_line(aes(colour = group))
g <- g + geom_point(aes(colour = group), alpha = 0.8)
g
```

[image]

For any *mapped* variable you can supress the appearance of a legend by using `guide = 'none'` in the appropriate `scale_...` call. eg.

```
g2 <- ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y, group = group)) + 
        geom_line(aes(colour = group)) +
        geom_point(aes(colour = group, alpha = 0.8))
g2 + scale_alpha(guide = 'none')
```

Which will return an identical plot

*EDIT* 
@Joran's comment is spot-on, I've made my answer more comprehensive

Comment: This is the correct method, since the OP is setting rather than mapping an aesthetic, but in general you can suppress the appearance of any legend using something like `g + scale_alpha(guide = "none")`.

Comment: Indeed. The answer has been elaborated upon. It does make more sense to have a comprehensive answer, not just specific to the OP issue.

Comment: Thanks so much for the added explanation. This goes a long way towards helping me understand the philosophy of ggplot.

Comment: I've been using ggplot for over a year and I NEVER understood the difference between a mapped or set variable. This is by far the best SO answer I've ever seen, congrats.

Comment: @joran your approach doesn't seem to work with the `group` argument :  `could not find function "scale_group"` ... A search [here](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/) didn't provide any insight on the proper function call to modify `group` aesthetics either.

Comment: @theforestecologist That's because the `group` aesthetic doesn't generate any scales or guides on its own. It's always sort of modifying something else. You'll never get a legend for the "group" aesthetic.

Comment: If alpha is outside aes for a boxplot and `alpha = 0` then the outliers are not visible. `show.legend = F` works better in this case.

Answer (score 80):

Just add the `show.legend = F` code after the part where you don't want it.

```
g <- ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y, group=group))
g <- g + geom_line(aes(colour=group))
g <- g + geom_point(aes(colour=group, alpha = .8), show.legend = F)
```

Comment: This is much more intuitive than mapping vs setting aesthetics (although that clears up a lot of misunderstanding too)

Answer (score 13):

Another simple option is using the function `guides`, which makes it possible to remove a particular aesthetic (fill, alpha, color) or multiple from the legend. Here is a reproducible example for removing only alpha legend and removing both alpha and color:

```r
df <- data.frame(x=rep(1:10,2), y=c(1:10,11:20), 
                 group=c(rep("a",10),rep("b",10)))
library(ggplot2)
g <- ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y, group=group))
g <- g + geom_line(aes(colour=group))
g <- g + geom_point(aes(colour=group, alpha = .8))
# Remove legend alpha
g + guides(alpha = "none")
```

[image]

```r
# Remove legend alpha and color
g + guides(alpha = "none", color = "none")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

For old versions of ggplot2 (versions before 0.9.2, released in late 2012), this answer should work:

I tried this with a `colour_scale` and it did not work. It appears that the `colour_scale_hue` item works like a function with a default parameter `TRUE`. I added `scale_colour_hue(legend=FALSE)` and it worked.

I am not sure if this is the case for all color scale items in ggplot

Comment: Using `legend` in a `scale_*` call is deprecated, better to do `scale_colour_hue(guide = "none")`.

Comment: taking into account that the `legend=FALSE` is deprecated, as pointed out by @shujaa comment, this is effectively a duplicate answer, i.e. to add the `guide = "none"` to a `scale_fill/color*` function.