# add stripplot from different data.frame

Tags: r, ggplot2

Using these 2 data.frames,

### ds.SG

```
> head(subset(ds.SG, mapped %in% c("rowA", "rowH")))
   starttime mapped meandist        se
1          0   rowA 126.2125  9.094259
8          0   rowH 113.3708  9.552690
9         60   rowA 134.4000 10.693561
16        60   rowH 115.8542  9.618504
17       120   rowA 148.9458 10.630781
24       120   rowH 124.8958 12.446691
```

### tdists

```
> head(subset(tdists, Group1=="rowA" & Group2=="rowH" & value<0.05))
    starttime Group2 Group1        value        vs
259       540   rowH   rowA 0.0273469043 rowA.rowH
287       600   rowH   rowA 0.0032981182 rowA.rowH
315       660   rowH   rowA 0.0170252864 rowA.rowH
343       720   rowH   rowA 0.0195995924 rowA.rowH
371       780   rowH   rowA 0.0047677680 rowA.rowH
399       840   rowH   rowA 0.0004149648 rowA.rowH
```

I can create the following 2 plots:

```
AB.distplot <-qplot(starttime, meandist, data=subset(ds.SG, mapped %in% c("rowA", "rowH")),
                    geom="line",colour=mapped, alpha=1)  
             + geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=meandist-se, ymax=meandist+se, alpha=0.1, fill=mapped, colour=NULL)) 
             + geom_line(size=1)
```

[image: mean distance +/- SE, by group at each time point]

```
AB.Tplot <-qplot(starttime, 0, data = subset(tdists, Group1=="rowA" & Group2=="rowH" & value<0.05))
```

[image: timepoints at which p-value for rowA and rowH distances is < 0.05]

I want to combine them such that `AB.Tplot` is overplotted on the bottom of `AB.distplot`

Following an idea I found [here](http://statistic-on-air.blogspot.ca/2014/02/ggplot2-histogram-with-jittered.html), I tried this:

```
AB.distplot + geom_point(
                 data = subset(tdists, Group1=="rowA" & Group2=="rowH" & value < 0.5), 
                 aes(starttime, 0), 
                 position = position_jitter(height=0.8), 
                 size=1)
#Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'mapped' not found
```

Since 'mapped' is only in `ds.SG`, I don't expect to find it in `tdists` (used in the `geom_point`). Why is `ggplot` looking for it and how can I overplot the way I'd like?

## Solution

Since @Joram didn't have all my data, he couldn't see exactly how the plot would turn out.  Following his excellent explanation, this is what I did and what I got:

```
tdists$y <- 0   
ggplot(data = subset(ds.SG, mapped %in% c("rowA", "rowH")),aes(x = starttime,y = meandist)) +  
    geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=meandist-se, ymax=meandist+se, fill=mapped), alpha=0.1) +
    geom_line(aes(colour = mapped),alpha = 1,size = 1) +
    geom_point(data = subset(tdists, Group1=="rowA" & Group2=="rowH" & value < 0.5),
                         aes(y = y), 
                         position = position_jitter(height=0), 
                         size=1)
```

[image: working plot]

Comment: You unmapped `colour` in `geom_ribbon` to avoid the same problem. You need to do it in `geom_point` as well.

Comment: @joran: actually, setting `colour=NULL` in `geom_ribbon` was just to get rid of the ribbon outlines. I didn't know it was solving another issue too. I just found this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11714951/remove-extra-legends-in-ggplot2?rq=1) about removing extra  legends which made me *finally* understand that mapping and setting could be 2 separate operations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is somewhat speculative, since I only have a tiny portion of your data to play with.

But I think it's time you stopped using `qplot`.

The reason you got that error is that aesthetic mappings are inherited between layers in **ggplot2**. So the aesthetics you mapped inside `qplot` are passed down to each subsequent layer, unless they are redefined or explicitly unmapped.

For this reason, when building up plots with lots of layers, using different data sets, using the more explicit `ggplot` notation is frequently much clearer.

I *think* this is more like what you're after:

```
tdists$y <- 0             
ggplot(data = subset(ds.SG, mapped %in% c("rowA", "rowH")),aes(x = starttime,y = meandist)) +  
    geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=meandist-se, ymax=meandist+se, alpha=0.1, fill=mapped, colour=NULL)) +
    geom_line(aes(colour = mapped),alpha = 1,size = 1) +
    geom_point(data = subset(tdists, Group1=="rowA" & Group2=="rowH" & value < 0.5),
               aes(y = y), 
               position = position_jitter(height=0.8), 
               size=1)
```

Your original `qplot` call should have essentially included a `geom_line` layer, so I'm not sure why you added another `geom_line` call. Perhaps it was covered up by the ribbon. Again, explicitly building up the layers starting with `ggplot()` makes this much clearer.