# Add layers from different datasets

Tags: r, ggplot2

I might be missing something very silly, can't get it to work. For example:

```
require(ggplot2)
#sample data
dat <- data.frame(x=1:5,
                  y=1:5,
                  z=1:5)
dat1 <- data.frame(x=1:5,
                   b=c(2,3,3,4,4))
```

Following works:

```
#This works:
ggplot(data=dat,aes(x=x,y=y,colour=z)) +
  geom_point()

#This works, too:
ggplot(data=dat1,aes(x=x,y=b)) +
  geom_line()
```

When I try to plot them together, it can't find `z`:

*Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'z' not found*

```
#This errors out
ggplot(data=dat,aes(x=x,y=y,colour=z)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line(data=dat1,aes(x=x,y=b))
```

**EDIT:**

Relevant post:
[add stripplot from different data.frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22844881/add-stripplot-from-different-data-frame)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example:

```
ggplot() +
  geom_point(data=dat,aes(x=x,y=y,colour=z)) +
  geom_line(data=dat1,aes(x=x,y=b))
```

Comment: This gives an error: `Error: ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class uneval`

Comment: @zx8754 I correct it. I don't know why the other doesn’t' work.

Comment: Thanks, this works. Also, found relevant post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22844881/add-stripplot-from-different-data-frame Does this mean my post is a duplicate? Solution from the other post is about inheritance between layers.

Comment: @agstudy the first argument to `ggplot()` is data, you initially fed it a mapping.

Comment: @baptiste I guess this alos. but `ggplot2` doc don't show the naming parameters...I should go in the code to see them.

Comment: ggplot is a generic, with hidden default methods. Still, the help page  `?ggplot` and `formals(ggplot2:::ggplot.data.frame)` show that the first argument is "data".

Comment: @baptiste Thanks. Maybe they should add this to the documentation.

Comment: @agstudy I'm confused, isn't it already [there?](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/ggplot.html)

Comment: @baptiste I am talking about the `...` parameters.  for example in the following example I need to set `mapping` then data...

Comment: @agstudy the order is different for geoms (layers), it's probably a source of confusion, yes, and you're correct in that `?layer` says nothing of the sort.