# Incorrect linetype in legend, ggplot2 in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have created a ggplot2 plot in R where a line is accompanied by a shaded confidence interval. However, the legend shows the wrong colour and symbol. Using scale_size_manual does not seem to correct the issue.

The plot:

[image: Line with confidence interval]

The input data:

```
my_example_data <- data.frame(Price = c(5,0,-5), Consumption = c(20,0,-20), Lower = c(17,-3,-21), Upper = c(21, 2, 23))
my_example_data.melt <- melt(my_example_data, id = "Price")

  Price    variable value
1     5 Consumption    20
2     0 Consumption     0
3    -5 Consumption   -20
4     5       Lower    17
5     0       Lower    -3
6    -5       Lower   -21
7     5       Upper    21
8     0       Upper     2
9    -5       Upper    23
```

The code to create the plot:

```
ggplot(subset(my_example_data.melt, variable == "Consumption"), aes(Price,value,fill='Mean response'), linetype=1) +
geom_line(colour="#000000")  +
coord_cartesian(xlim = c(-100, 100),ylim = c(-0.75, 1)) +
geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = subset(my_example_data.melt, variable == "Lower")$value, ymax = subset(my_example_data.melt, variable == "Upper")$value,fill = 'SD of response'),alpha=0.3, colour=NA) +
xlab("Change in relative price [Δ€]") +
ylab("Change in consumption [MW]") +
theme(legend.position="bottom", legend.direction="horizontal") +
xlab("Change in relative price [Δ€]") +
ylab("Change in consumption [MW]") +
scale_fill_discrete("")
```

Is there a manual override option for changing the linetypes and colour for the plot and legend without having to add additional information to the melted dataframe?

Comment: The restrictions you are place on the plotting region don't really make any sense. The value variable has a range of [-20, 20] but you have: ylim = c(-0.75, 1). There is a corresponding mismatch in the xlim range. When you take those out you do see a plot that looks like what you show above, but the only color that is specified is black ("#000000") and that is the color of the line. The character value 'SD of response' doesn't really match any variable so I'm wondering if you think ggplot2 functions have some sort of clairvoyance?

Comment: The xlim and ylim are leftovers from me using real (proprietary) data. They have no impact on the colouring when I remove them.

Answer (score 0):

You will find this much easier not using the melted data.

Also quoting from [Remove extra legends in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11714951/remove-extra-legends-in-ggplot2/11714990#11714990),

Aesthetics can be set or mapped within a ggplot call.

- An aesthetic defined within aes(...) is mapped from the data, and a legend created.
- An aesthetic may also be set to a single value, by defining it outside  aes().

Therefore something like

```
 ggplot(my_example_data,aes(x=Price)) + 
   geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=Lower,ymax=Upper),fill='blue',alpha=0.5) +  
   geom_line(aes(y=Consumption))
```

[image]

or perhaps If you really wanted a  legend, you could use `scale_identity`

```
ggplot(my_example_data,aes(x=Price)) + 
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=Lower,ymax=Upper,fill='blue'), alpha=0.5) + 
  geom_line(aes(y=Consumption)) + 
  scale_fill_identity(guide='legend', name = 'Your name', label = 'whatever')
```

[image]

Comment: This still doesn't have a legend for the black line. Can ggplot2 not achieve this when different plot types (geom_ribbon and geom_line) are used?

Comment: @fifthace -- the second options gives you the approach to use - some thinking on your behalf may be required.