# incorrect linetype in geom_vline with legend in r ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I am trying to display the xvar median as a dotted line & show it in the legend. Here's my code:

```
require(ggplot2)
require(scales)

medians_mtcars <- data.frame("wt.median"=median(mtcars$wt))

# legend shows but linetype is wrong (solid)
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg))
p <- p + geom_point()
p <- p + geom_vline(aes(xintercept=wt.median, linetype="dotted"),
                    data=medians_mtcars, show_guide=TRUE)
p
```

I also tried:

```
# linetype is correct but legend does not show
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg))
p <- p + geom_point()
p <- p + geom_vline(aes(xintercept=wt.median),
                    data=medians_mtcars, show_guide=TRUE, linetype="dotted")
p
```

Would have liked to post the plot images, but haven't crossed the reputation threshold yet.

There were 2 other posts on this forum that comes close to this topic but does not offer a solution to this problem:
[Add vline to existing plot and have it appear in ggplot2 legend?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12545322/add-vline-to-existing-plot-and-have-it-appear-in-ggplot2-legend)
;
[Incorrect linetype in legend, ggplot2 in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25253624/incorrect-linetype-in-legend-ggplot2-in-r)

I am using ggplot2 version 1.0.0

What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to show linetype in legend and also change it then inside `aes()` you can just write name for that linetype (as you have only one line) and then change linetype with `scale_linetype_manual()`.

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) + 
      geom_point() + 
      geom_vline(aes(xintercept=wt.median, linetype="media"),
                    data=medians_mtcars, show_guide=TRUE)+
      scale_linetype_manual(values="dotted")
```

If you really want to type linetype in `aes()` and also get correct legend then you should use `scale_linetype_identity()` with argument `guide="legend"`.

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) + 
      geom_point() + 
      geom_vline(aes(xintercept=wt.median, linetype="dotted"),
                    data=medians_mtcars,show_guide=TRUE)+
      scale_linetype_identity(guide="legend")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Didzis. My task contains more than one line (e.g. mean, median, sd, etc.) and I simplified it for this post. I am still curious as to how I can specify the line type constant in aes mapping so that the legend automatically shows with the specified linetype correctly.

Comment: That did it. Thanks a lot. Now I need to go see what scale_*_identity does.