# Taking away letters superimposed to points in ggplot legend

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, legend, scatter

I'm doing some scatterplots with labels added, something like this:

```
require(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt, fill=factor(cyl))) + geom_point(shape=21, size=4) + 
  geom_text((aes(label=rownames(mtcars), color=factor(cyl))))
```

[image]

If you look closely at the legend, you'll see the letter 'a' over the drawing
of the points (each with different color, of course). I want a way to
eliminate this, but I keep trying with `guides` and `guide_legends` to no
avail. The legend I would like should look like in this other plot:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt, fill=factor(cyl))) + geom_point(shape=21, size=4)
```

[image]

Thanks in advance,
Juan

Comment: Does [this question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11714951/4002530) help?