# Remove "group" legend in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

So a handful of posts already address how to remove unwanted legends in ggplot.

The [wonderful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11714990/4581200) posted to ["Remove extra legends in ggplot2"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11714951/4581200)
 suggests:

> For any mapped variable you can supress the appearance of a legend by using `guide = 'none'` in the appropriate `scale_`...

However, I'm having problems with **unwanted legends being created by adding the `group` aesthetic**. 
I tried the scale approach, but it  doesn't seem to work with the group argument:

```
could not find function "scale_group"
```

A search [here](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/) didn't provide any insight on the proper function call to modify group aesthetics either.

User @joran [provided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11714951/remove-extra-legends-in-ggplot2/11714990#comment88037663_11714990) the following insight in the linked post above:

> That's because the `group` aesthetic doesn't generate any scales or guides on its own. It's always sort of modifying something else. You'll never get a legend for the `group` aesthetic.

---

**Example**

So I could just add `show.legend = FALSE` to my function call containing `group` to remove any legend for that function, but this doesn't work out if I want some *other* portion (i.e., aesthetic) of that call to be included in the legend.

```
#Set Up Example:

library(lme4)
library(ggplot2)

mod <- lmer(mpg ~ hp + (1 |cyl), data = mtcars)
pred <- predict(mod,re.form = NA)
pdat <- data.frame(mtcars[,c('hp','cyl')], mpg = pred, up = pred+1, low = pred-1)
```

Adding `show.legend = F` to function calls work as expected:

```
gp <- 
  ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = hp, y = mpg, color = cyl, group = cyl), show.legend = F) +
  geom_point(aes(group = cyl),show.legend = F) +
  facet_wrap(~cyl) + 
  geom_line(data = pdat, aes(group = cyl),show.legend = F, color = 'orange')
```

But when I want to add a legend for a `geom_ribbon` fill based on the same `group` (and therefore *cannot* use the `show.legend = F` argument), I get a legend for my `group` again...

```
gp + geom_ribbon(data = pdat, aes(ymin = low, ymax = up, group = cyl, fill = 'mod'), alpha = 0.3) + 
scale_fill_manual(values=c("orange"), name="model")
```

**The outputs:**

[image]

Comment: It's because it's inheriting the `color` aesthetic (you can see it in the outline of the ribbons). If you only set that in `geom_point`, it will go away.

Comment: @alistaire ohhhhh. So by assigning `color` in the main `ggplot ` function call, all subsequent function calls are "activating" (not sure the right word to use) the `color` call (and thus creating a legend for it unless supressed using `show.legend=F`)? Is that right?

Comment: @theforestecologist: what's your expected output? only `model` legend without `cyl` gradient scale?

Comment: Use `inherit.aes = FALSE` such as `geom_ribbon(data = pdat, 
                 aes(x = hp, ymin = low, ymax = up, group = cyl, fill = 'mod'), 
                 inherit.aes = FALSE,
                 alpha = 0.3)`

Comment: @theforestecologist Yep, provided that geom plots the aesthetic in some way (here the outline of the ribbon). If you look in a geom's docs (`?geom_ribbon` here), it will tell you which aesthetics it understands.

Comment: @Tung yes. my expected output is to have colored points without a legend (i.e., without the `cyl` gradient scale) but to have a legend for my "`model`" ribbons. I can see now that the issue lies with the `color` aesthetic, not with `group` directly. Your `inherit.aes` argument also works great in this situation (after adding the necessary `x` `aes` to the ribbon function).  Thanks! :)

Comment: @theforestecologist: nice, good to know the problem was solved!

Answer (score 0):

The last geom cover the first geom, you can try this

```
ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = hp, y = mpg, color = cyl, group = cyl), show.legend = F) +
  geom_point(aes(group = cyl)) +                             
  facet_wrap(~cyl) + 
  geom_line(data = pdat, aes(group = cyl),color = 'orange') 

gp + geom_ribbon(data = pdat, aes(ymin = low, ymax = up, group = cyl, fill = 'mod'),       alpha = 0.3) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("orange"), name="model")+
  scale_color_continuous(guide ='none')
```

By the way, my idea comes from the link you posted at the top.