# Adding a legend to a ggplot that combines geom_line and geom_shape using R

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I have the following MWE:

```
library(scales)
library(tidyverse)

Canada <- c(383.927, 387.088, 390.648, 393.926, 395.947, 393.98, 388.772, 
392.391, 391.804, 389.321, 390.583, 390.062, 390.596, 392.19, 
392.267, 397.572, 397.807, 394.64, 391.737, 392.659, 392.483, 
392.012, 391.842, 394.06, 391.661, 390.621, 392.533, 396.218, 
401.802, 397.298, 392.468, 392.056, 394.752, 392.947, 392.606, 
391.839, 392.169, 393.29, 399.993, 396.114, 403.1, 398.263, 395.066, 
397.16, 399.562, 396.865, 392.898, 396.89, 398.529, 402.269, 
-9.999e+09, 398.294, 401.033, 399.328, -9.999e+09, 400.062, 395.829, 
397.754, 395.306, 394.87, 398.469, 399.91, 405.053, 404.678, 
402.185, 396.605, -9.999e+09, 402.252, 405.295, 401.08, 400.527, 
398.38, 400.152, 396.42, 402.497, 406.855, 403.56, -9.999e+09, 
-9.999e+09, 405.773, 402.306, 403.146, 403.079, 400.712)

Canada1 <- c(390.704083333333, 393.322083333333, 393.900083333333, 396.780833333333, 
398.3274, 401.312181818182, 402.45)

x.axis <- c("Jan. 2010","","","","","July 2010","","","","","",
"Dec. 2010","","","","","","July 2011","","","","","",
"Dec. 2011","","","","","","July 2012","","","","","",
"Dec. 2012","","","","","","July 2013","","","","","",
"Dec. 2013","","","","","","July 2014","","","","","",
"Dec. 2014","","","","","","July 2015","","","","","",
"Dec. 2015","","","","","","July 2016","","","","","",
"Dec. 2016","")

# Edit
d1 <- as.Date(paste0("201001","01"), "%Y%m%d")
d2 <- as.Date(paste0("201612","01"), "%Y%m%d")
date1 <- format(seq(d1,d2,by="month"), "%Y%m%d")
datCan <- data.frame(co2 = Canada, labels = as.character(time), date = date1, group = 1)
d1 <- as.Date(paste0("201006","01"), "%Y%m%d")
d2 <- as.Date(paste0("201606","01"), "%Y%m%d")
date2 <- format(seq(d1,d2,by="year"), "%Y%m%d")
dat2Can <- data.frame(co2 = Canada1, date = date2, group = 2)

Canplot <- ggplot() + geom_line(data = datCan, aes(x = date, y = co2, group = group)) 
  + geom_line(data = dat2Can, linetype = "dashed", aes(x = date, y = co2, group = group), color = "Red")
  + geom_point(data = dat2Can, size=2, aes(x = date, y = co2, group = group), color = "Red")
  + ylim(380,410) + scale_x_discrete(labels = x.axis)
  + theme_classic(base_size=12) + ylab("yval")
  + xlab("Time") + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust=1))
```

Which produces

[image]

I want to add a legend to this plot but am having troubles because of my inclusion of `geom_line` and `geom_point`. I believe I need to do it this way because the points are in specific locations. Any idea as to how I can do this? I am open to creating a standalone legend that is just a black line and red dashed line with a circle in the middle of it. This would work fine because I am using LaTeX to format my document anyway.

Comment: You can visit [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11714951/remove-extra-legends-in-ggplot2)

Comment: Your cdoe does not produce the same graph on my session, are you sure about "-9.999e+09" this values ?

Comment: @dc37 sorry I forgot a chunk of my code, see the above edit

Comment: On your example, what is `time` in your `datCan` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get two different legends for different dataframes, you can have the use of `new_color_scale` function from `ggnewscale` package.

Here, I used `lubridate` to add date sequences to your individual vectors for lines and points and then I create dataframes from those:

```r
library(lubridate)
date_seq = seq(ymd("2010-01-01"),ymd("2016-12-01"),length.out = length(Canada))
date_seq_point = seq(ymd("2010-06-01"),ymd("2016-06-01"),length.out = length(Canada1))

Can <- data.frame(Canada = Canada,
                  Xaxis = date_seq,
                  dataset = "Lines")

Can_point = data.frame(Canada = Canada1,
                       Xaxis = date_seq_point,
                       dataset2 ="Points")
```

Now, you can do the plot with these new dataframes and get the appropriate legend for both lines and points when calling `new_color_scale`:

```r
library(ggnewscale)
library(ggplot2)

ggplot()+
  geom_line(data = Can, aes(x = Xaxis, y = Canada, color = dataset))+
  scale_color_manual(name = "Lines",values = "black")+
  new_scale_color()+
  geom_line(data = Can_point, aes(x  = Xaxis, y = Canada, color = dataset2))+
  geom_point(data = Can_point, aes(x  = Xaxis, y = Canada, color = dataset2))+
  scale_color_manual(name = "Points",values = "red")+
  ylim(380,410)+
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "6 months", date_labels = "%b %Y")+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))
```

[image]

---

**EDIT: two different legends in one legends**

As per OP's request, the goal is to keep one legend for Lines and Points but not having points displayed in the legend of lines.

So, you can bind together both dataframes by doing:

```r
library(lubridate)
date_seq = seq(ymd("2010-01-01"),ymd("2016-12-01"),length.out = length(Canada))
date_seq_point = seq(ymd("2010-06-01"),ymd("2016-06-01"),length.out = length(Canada1))

Can <- data.frame(Canada = Canada,
                  Xaxis = date_seq,
                  dataset = "Lines")

Can_point = data.frame(Canada = Canada1,
                       Xaxis = date_seq_point,
                       dataset ="Points")

DF <- rbind(Can, Can_point)
```

Then, you can plot lines and points in function of each dataset but control shape of points by adding `shape` argument into `aes`. Then, you can set the shape of black points to be NA in `scale_shape_manual`:

```r
library(ggplot2) 

ggplot(DF, aes(x = Xaxis, y = Canada, color = dataset, shape = dataset))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_line()+
  ylim(380,410)+
  scale_color_manual(values = c("black","red"))+
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(NA,16))
```

[image]

Does it answer your question ?

Comment: Yes, Ill have to go through and see if it is compatible with my code. Although, both the legend entries have a dot in them when the first should just be a black line and the second a red dashed line with a dot in it

Comment: I edited my answer accordingly. Let me know if it is working for you.

Comment: I don't want two separate legends, just one that has the entries that you have there! So just one with the title "Legend" and then points and lines exactly as you have it

Comment: Please check my edited answer. Let me know if it is what you are looking for.