# How do I remove this size label on my plot while increasing the point size?

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, visualization, point

I have this R code below:

```
ggplot(group_data_1,aes(avg.yield,final_boxes_crop,color=final_cce_adm1))+geom_point(aes(size=1)) + theme(plot.caption = element_text(size = 10,face = "italic", colour = "black"), panel.grid.major = element_line(size = 2),panel.grid.minor = element_line(colour = "darkolivegreen4",size = 0.8), axis.title = element_text(family = "Bookman",face = "bold.italic", colour = "brown3"),plot.title = element_text(face = "bold",colour = "blue"),legend.text = element_text(face = "bold"),panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white",colour = "azure4", size = 2, linetype = "solid"),plot.background = element_rect(fill = "aliceblue"),legend.key = element_rect(fill = NA),legend.background = element_rect(fill = "ivory1")) +labs(title = "Average yield by crop and region",x = "Average Yield", y = "Crop", colour = "Region",subtitle = "This graph shows the average yield for each crop and region that crop cuts were conducted in",caption = "The graph above shows that worst affected region was Upper West and North East Region. The best performing regions were Northern and Bono.")
```

Which gives the following plot:

[image: Plot from the code]

What I want to do is to increase the size of the points but remove the *size label* on the right. This label shows up when I add the argument in `geom_point(aes(size=1))` but I cannot seem to get rid of it.

Comment: Try: `geom_point(size = 1)`

Comment: An aesthetic defined within aes(...) is mapped from the data, and a legend created. See here <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11714951/remove-extra-legends-in-ggplot2>. I will close as it is duplicate.