# Geom_point : when using color and alpha : how to delete the alpha legend in ggplot?

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, alpha, geom-point

I have this df that is visualized as followed:

```
df = data.frame(x = -10:11,
                y = seq(-5,5.5,by=0.5),
                z = rep(c(1,2),11) )

df

ggplot(df)+aes(x=x,y=y,color=factor(z),alpha=z)+
  geom_point()+
  geom_hline(yintercept=0)+
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0)+
  theme_blank()
```

The output:
[image]

I checked all similar questions but nothing has worked out to remove the alpha legend. Thanks.

Comment: Add   +guides(alpha=F)

Comment: Check the most recent answer -  [Remove extra legends in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11714951/remove-extra-legends-in-ggplot2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add in `alpha` in aesthetics and use `guides` to remove it like this:

```r
df = data.frame(x = -10:11,
                y = seq(-5,5.5,by=0.5),
                z = rep(c(1,2),11) )
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df)+aes(x=x,y=y,color=factor(z), alpha=z)+
  geom_point()+
  geom_hline(yintercept=0)+
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0) +
  guides(alpha = "none")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-01-20 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>