# How can I remove the "colour" label from the legend in my ggplot2 code?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am not used to working with `geom_col()` ggplot2 code, so I'm trying to figure out how to remove the "colour" item from my "fill" scale. How can I do this?

Below is the data and code:

```
# Open necessary library
library(ggplot2)

# Datasest
data <- data.frame(name = c("prog1","prog2","prog3","prog4",
                            "prog1","prog2","prog3","prog4"), 
                   factor = c("fact1","fact1","fact1","fact1",
                              "fact2","fact2","fact2","fact2"), 
                   price = c(1,2,3,4,
                             10,11,12,13), 
                   sem = c(0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,
                           0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1))

# Define custom color palette
color_palette <- c("#000000","#E69F00","#56B4E9","#D55E00")

# Generate the graph
ggplot(data, aes(x = name, y = price, group = factor, fill = factor, col = 'black'))+
  geom_col(position = "dodge", width = 0.6)+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = price, ymax = price + sem), width = 0.3, position = position_dodge(0.5), col = "black") +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(NULL))+
  xlab("Scale")+
  ylab("Xlabel")+
  ggtitle("Title",
          subtitle = "Subtitle")+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust=0.5, size = 16),
        plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust=0.5, size = 14),
        axis.text = element_text(size = 13),
        axis.title = element_text(size = 13),
        legend.key.size = unit(0.6, 'cm'))+
  scale_fill_manual(values = color_palette)+
  scale_color_manual(values = color_palette)+
  coord_flip()
```

Comment: Remove `col = 'black'` from the first line and add it after the `width = 0.6` on the second line - ie `geom_col(position = "dodge", width = 0.6, col = "black")` - as an aside, I dont think you need the `group = factor` in the first line

Comment: Remove `col = 'black'` from inside `aes`. You can put `color = 'black'` as an argument directly into `geom_col` if you want black lines around the columns.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove extra legends in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11714951/remove-extra-legends-in-ggplot2)

Comment: @jpsmith @Allan Cameron @Paul Stafford Allen Yes, that helps, thank you! I was trying to keep the `col = 'black'` because the lower end of the error bar blended in with the border, making it look nicer. Any way to keep the border and remove the label?

Comment: @ihb did you add `col = "black"` in the `geom_col` line as recommended above?

Comment: @jpsmith I just did! Thank you, appreciate that. Feel free to answer this question and I'll accept it from you.